# What is the Hadamard's Factorization of a function that has a finite number of zeros (2)

Tags: complex-analysis

The motivation to this question can be found in

[What is the Hadamard's Factorization of a function that has a finite number of zeros](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285115/what-is-the-hadamards-factorization-of-a-function-that-has-a-finite-number-of-z)

My **question** here is: I deduce that the function $h(s)$ has a finite number of roots in $(0,1)$. However how I can see that the corresponfing entire function $h(s)$ has also a finite number of roots in the whole complex plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing at least something more about $h$, you can't conclude that. The function $f(z) = \sin z$ has no zeros in $(0,1)$ but infinitely many zeros in the whole plane.

Comment: @ mrf: The function $f$ is the derivative of the Dirichlet series of the Hasse--Weil L-function of a modular curve $C$  over $Q$ .

Comment: Is the $f$ in this comment the $h$ in the question? and, if so, why was this information not in the question? (and, if not, then what does it mean?)

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson : No, $f$ in this comment is not the $h$ in the question.